# Node.js program using knex and google cloud sql connector doesnt exit

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, cloud, knex.js

```
const Knex = require('knex');
const { Connector } = require('@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector');


const connectWithConnector = async () => {
    const connector = new Connector();
    const clientOpts = await connector.getOptions({
        instanceConnectionName: "my-instance-connection-name",
        ipType: 'PUBLIC',
    });
    const dbConfig = {
        client: 'pg',
        connection: {
            ...clientOpts,
            user: 'my-user',
            password: 'my-user-password',
            database: 'my-database',
        }
    };

    return Knex(dbConfig);
};

const useDatabase = async () => {
    try {
        const databaseKnex = await connectWithConnector();


        console.log('Destroy');

        await databaseKnex.destroy();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
};

useDatabase();
```

I tried write it multiple ways, but everytime process doesn't finish after executing this code. Please help. I want to connect to Google Cloud SQL using knex. It seems like destroy() isn't working

Comment: Why are you trying to tear down the connection pool immediately after connecting?

Comment: @MichelFloyd This is just example, between connecting and destroy will be used some querying on database.

Comment: It is not normally required to `.destroy` after a query.

Comment: @MichelFloyd, but still program doesn't finish execution after query or anything. How to prevent it?

Comment: Instead of an `await` try resolving `.destroy()` and `catch`ing any errors directly. `databaseKnex.destroy().then(() => console.log('destroyed')).catch((error) => console.error(error))` - see if you can get any extra info out. The program should also terminate. Alternatively, try stepping into `.destroy()` in your debugger and seeing what is actually going on there in the GCP context.